# JavaCV working/writing to BufferdImage after face detection

Tags: java, opencv, face-detection, javacv

I am successfully detecting faces using JavaCV, it's not totally accurate but good enough for the moment.

However, for testing purposes and with a look at the future (this is only part of a bigger group project), I want to write rectangles onto the faces using BufferedImage and Graphics.drawRect().

I am aware of the fact that you can draw rects to faces using JavaCV with the static methods, but it's not what I need / want to do. 
If I, after the scanning process, try to load the image using ImageIO and try to write rects to it, the application ends with a native error.

**Is there any way I can command openCV to "release" the image (because I think that's the soruce of the problem, that opencv does not release the image file.) ?**

Thanks in advance

edit: error code:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fc705dafac4, pid=8216, tid=140493568964352
#
# JRE version: 7.0_21-b02
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjpeg.so.8+0x1eac4]  jpeg_save_markers+0x84
```

edit:

```
 cvReleaseImage(inputImage);
            cvReleaseImage(grayImage);
            cvClearMemStorage(storage);
```

didnt help too

Answer (score 0):

You can draw simple rectangles without Graphics.drawRect();
Theres a nice way to set pixels of a BufferedImage in java.

`try {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("img.png"));
    int x, y;
    int width, hight;
    Color color = Color.black;
    y = 50;
    x = 50;
    width = 90;
    hight = 90;
    for(int i=x;i<=width;i++){
    img.setRGB(i, y, color.getRGB());
    img.setRGB(i, hight, color.getRGB());
    for(int i=y;i<=hight;i++){
        img.setRGB(x, i, color.getRGB());
        img.setRGB(width, i, color.getRGB());
    }
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("!!!IOException!!!");
}`

I hope this will help.

NoName

Answer (score 0):

Check your operating system running , and install 64-bit opencv if your lap is running on 64 bit OS.[This link](http://codeadapter.blogspot.in/2014/02/how-to-detect-features-objects-face-eye.html) may help you a lot